# Store more logs in-memory with systemd-journald

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I know `systemd-journald` keeps its logs in-memory by default.

Does anyone know what the limit is for these logs and how to increase it? From the banner at the top it seems like it is only keeping them for 3 hours:

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2018-11-20 06:40:21 CET, end at Tue 2018-11-20 09:56:45 CET. --
```

I want `systemd-journald` to log more, but I don't want to turn on persistence because it's running on a Raspberry Pi and I want to prevent the SD card from going corrupt because of the writes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant options from `journald.conf` when using `volatile` storage are  the ones prefixed with "Runtime":
`RuntimeMaxUse=`, `RuntimeKeepFree=`, `RuntimeMaxFileSize=` and `RuntimeMaxFiles=`

Per [the manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html):

> The options prefixed with "Runtime" apply to the journal files when
>   stored on a volatile in-memory file system, more specifically
>   `/run/log/journal`

so you'll have to play with:
`RuntimeMaxUse=` how much space logs can take up in the `/run` file system
and
`RuntimeKeepFree=` how much free space that should remain in the `/run` file system after logs are saved

Per the same manual, `systemd-journald` will respect both limits and use the smaller of the two values: the first one defaults to 10% and the second to 15% of the size of the respective file system, but each value is capped to 4G.
Do note that [those options accept only absolute values + unit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296054/22142).

Answer (score -1):

in your journald config file:

> /etc/systemd/journald.conf

You should have some predefined options. dehash the option:

> Storage=persistant

and then create the a journal directory in /var/log/journal. If the directory is not there, journald will not store logs between reboots.

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/journal
```

Also the flags -a "all"  and -m "merege" will collect all the logs even from other users. and then using --since will give you solid ranges.

```
journalctl --since "2018-01-01 08:30:00" -xema
```

adding -f will give you follow and show logs as they come in

Comment: Please, no persistence.